# Difficulty understanding type difference of "&" call operator and "Start-Process" inside switch parameter

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am having a difficult time totally understanding the difference between the *&* call operator and *Start-Process* when using a *[switch]* parameter to access an external .CMD script.

In my case, I am using an optional switch parameter in part of my script to allow an external CMD script to run when the switch parameter is used. However, I initially wanted to use the *&* call operator to call the CMD script, and ran into an error (see below). When *&* is used, it appears to use a value type of *System.Object[]*, and appears to want to convert it to the *[switch]* parameter type.

If I change how I'm running the external script by using *Start-Process* instead of *&*, everything works.

What is actually happening here with the two different methods of calling the external script? I'm not totally clear on what the *[switch]* value type is and how it interacts with the *System.Object[]* type the *&* operator seems to be using.

As you can see, I have my code working, but would love to have some clarification between *&* and *Start-Process* types, and how they interact when accessed by using a *[switch]* parameter.

I haven't been able to find any information online pertaining to this specific case of using *[switch]* with relation to *&* call. Any suggested reading is also very much appreciated!

Thanks for your help in advance.

### Examples:

## Script fails to run if '&' operator is used to run the external script

```
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set2", mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Package,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set2", mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$PackagePath
)

$Package = If ( $(Try { 
        Test-Path -LiteralPath $PackagePath.trim() }
        Catch { $false } )) { & $PackagePath }
    Else { 
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell; 
        $wshell.Popup("The path '$PackagePath' does not exist.") }

>  > .\testing.ps1 -Package -PackagePath C:\The\Path\ToScript.cmd
```

#### Error:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
"System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
At C:\testing.ps1:8 char:92
+ ...  $false } )) { & $PackagePath }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

## Script runs if '&' call operator is replaced by 'Start-Process'

```
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set2", mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Package,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set2", mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$PackagePath
)

$Package = If ( $(Try { 
        Test-Path -LiteralPath $PackagePath.trim() }
        Catch { $false } )) { Start-Process $PackagePath }
    Else { 
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell; 
        $wshell.Popup("The path '$PackagePath' does not exist.") }

>  > .\testing.ps1 -Package -PackagePath C:\The\Path\ToScript.cmd
```

#### External script runs:

```
cmdlet testing.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
PackagePath: d:\build_packages\build_package.cmd
```

Comment: `$Package =` -> `${Some other variable name, which does not collide with $Package parameter} =`

Answer (score 0):

The `$Package` variable, first specified in the `Param`, is a "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter" type. Try the following script that tries to assign different types to the `$Package` variable.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="set2", mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Package
)

Write-Host $Package.GetType()

if ($Package) {
    Write-Host $Package
    Write-Host "another" + $Package.GetType()
}

$Package = $True
$Package = "now"
```